# Compactness with Ascoli-Arzelà?

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, compactness, proof-verification

> Let 
>   $$
> K:= \{x: [0,T] \to \mathbb R: x^{\prime}(t)=x^2(t), \, 0\le x(T) \le 1\}.
> $$
>   Prove that $K$ is a compact subset of $C([0,T],\mathbb R)$.

My idea is to use Ascoli-Arzelà thm. First of all, by some routine calculations I have found that 
$$
K= \left\{x:[0,T] \to \mathbb R: x(t)=\frac{x(T)}{x(T)(T-t)+1}, \, 0\le x(T) \le 1\right\}
$$

Then I have shown that

1. $K$ is *equibounded*:
   $$
   \vert x(t)\vert\le\left\vert \frac{x(T)}{(T-t)x(T)+1}\right\vert \le x(T) \le 1
   $$
   for every $t \in[0,T]$ and for every $x(\cdot) \in K$.
2. $K$ is *equicontinuous*: indeed the following holds true
   $$
   \vert x(t_1)-x(t_2) \vert \le \vert t_1 -t_2 \vert 
   $$
   for every $t_1,t_2 \in[0,T]$ and for every $x(\cdot) \in K$.

Finally I have to show that $K$ is closed: let us take $x_n \to x$ uniformly s.t. $x^{\prime}_n = x_n^2$ for every $n$. Then $x_n^2 \to x^2$ uniformly; to sum up we have

- $x_n \to x$ uniformly;
- $x^{\prime}_n = x_n^2 \to x^2$ uniformly.

Hence $x$ is differentiable and $x^{\prime}=x^2$.

Is my proof correct? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's correct. I would only add after the

> let us take $x_n \to x$ uniformly s.t. $x^{\prime}_n = x_n^2$ for every $n$. Then $x_n^2 \to x^2$ uniformly;

the justification that $\{x_n\}$ is uniformly bounded by $1$.

Comment: Hi Davide, thank you very much for your kind and useful correction. Thank you also for editing tags, I did not know the "proof verification" tag. Thanks!